# Statically link a GTK + WebKit 1.0 application

Tags: webkit, gtk, static-linking

I created *or adapted* this simple `webkit-1.0` demo (consisting only of a window with a webview inside displaying a local HTML file):

```
// From: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/WebKitGtk/ProgrammingGuide/Tutorial
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <webkit/webkit.h>

static void destroyWindowCb(GtkWidget* widget, GtkWidget* window) { gtk_main_quit(); }
static gboolean closeWebViewCb(WebKitWebView* webView, GtkWidget* window) { gtk_widget_destroy(window); return TRUE; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *main_window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), 800, 600);
    WebKitWebView *webView = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(main_window), GTK_WIDGET(webView));
    g_signal_connect(main_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroyWindowCb), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(webView, "close", G_CALLBACK(closeWebViewCb), main_window);
    webkit_web_view_load_uri(webView, ".../test.html");
    gtk_widget_grab_focus(GTK_WIDGET(webView));
    gtk_widget_show_all(main_window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this application with

```
g++ owb.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 webkit-1.0`
```

works fine. **But I want to create a static build of this** and therefore I use the following command:

```
g++ owb.cpp -static `pkg-config --static --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 webkit-1.0`
```

But this command results in a heavy error message:

```
$ g++ owb.cpp -static `pkg-config --static --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 webkit-1.0`
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebkitgtk-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljavascriptcoregtk-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lffi
... some warnings skipped ...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I try `ldconfig -p | grep gdk_pixbuf-2.0` I get:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep gdk_pixbuf-2.0
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so
```

and all the other libraries, too.

**So what's wrong?**

Comment: `.so` indicates a shared library, not a static library. Using GTK+ as a static library is **unsupported**, so you will need to build it (and WebKitGTK+) yourself and hope nothing breaks. Good luck!